# Use of undeclared identifier error in simple snake game

Tags: c++

I'm trying to design a simple snake game. Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;

//Map Dimentions
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;

//Positions
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;

//Directions
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, Left, Right, Up, Down};
eDirection dir;

void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;

    //Center Snake Head
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;

    //Randomly places fruit within constraints of map
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;

    score = 0;
}

void Draw() {
    //Clears Terminal Window
    system("clear");


    //Walls of Map
    for(int j = 0 ; j < height ; ++j)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < width ;++i)
        {
            if( i == 0 || i == (width - 1) || j == 0 || j == (height - 1)  )
            {
                cout << "* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "  ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;

    **}﻿**

}

void Input() {


}

void Logic() {


}


int main () {

    Setup();
    while (!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

At the beginning of my code document, I have all c++ libraries included. On the last } of my Walls of Map, surrounded in ****'s, I receive the error  " Use of undeclared identifier " ". I have no idea what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `**}**` supposed to do according to you?

Comment: You're not including any headers and yet you're using e.g. `cout`.

Comment: The **** are just surrounding the problem they're not actually in my code and I have every single #include at the top before my snippet

Comment: Looks like you have some illegal, non-printable characters in there. Delete the blank lines around the `**}**` to kill them. [Wipe them out. All of them.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CP9dg38cAI)

Comment: Post a full [mcve] so a copy paste from it to a cpp file generates the error when built.  Use a comment to mark the line.  Include the build command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a theory, I pulled up the file in an antique text editor and I see

```
**}?**
```

Hex editor says

```
20 20 20 20 2A 2A 7D 3F 2A 2A
```

That 3F shouldn't be there.

Comment: there was an invisible character following the }. Thank's for the fix